# How to generate a manifest.appcache from a template?

Tags: templates

I have a web app built with ExpressionEngine (2.8.0 at present) and I want to use it to auto-generate an appcache manifest file (I have been generating it manually).

I can generate the **content** of the manifest easily enough with a standard template, and I can use htaccess to…

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

…but how best can I get the output of my template served as a **.appcache** file?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't thought about this before but you could do it with a bit of PHP in a template.

The PHP would loop through any directories you specify and output the names of files you wish to cache - either directly or writing to a separate cache manifest file (I'd try the former).

To do this you'd need to create a template and turn on PHP for the output stage then within that write your PHP.

Something like this should get you started http://motyar.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/creating-cache-manifest-file-using-php.html

This approach seems a bit "scatter-gun". I think it would be better to only cache files that were used. I'm not sure how to achieve that but maybe the answer is simply to ensure that assets you wish to cache are in particular directories away from assets you don't wish to cache.

Comment: Thanks. I may give that a go, though I prefer not to use PHP in templates. I had hoped I might get what I need by using Rob Sanchez's [http header](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/http-header) plugin to simply serve my template as **text/cache-manifest**. But even though my template is definitely now being served as that mime-type, it seems not to be recognised as a legitimate manifest. Hmm.

Comment: You could wrap all the PHP in a plugin so you wouldn't need to expose any of it. I think there are 2 issues here though, generating the manifest and serving it correctly. I'd say that the latter is a server config issue rather than an EE one.

Comment: Yup, a plugin would be the way to go but that's beyond me at present. However, the good news is that the **http header** approach actually does work. It wasn't working before because there were 2 invalid image URLs in my manifest due to a syntax error on my part! Once I fixed those, my template functions as a manifest just fine. I'm aware that older browsers may not recognise it without the right file ending but for now the app only needs to work on iOS7 anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your input and motyar link though.